# Call a function on the first cell in a UICollectionView when it has finished loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating an Objective-C iOS application that features a full screen horizontally scrolling `UICollectionView` of images.

How can I create a function that is called on the first cell in the `UICollectionView` whenever the `UICollectionView` has finished loading its content?

Comment: if your downloading the image then at completion block do your thing thats simple . Or if you are loading local image then right after loading image call your function

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    callFunction()
}
return cell;
}
```

or if you are downloading the images you can call the function in completion block

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to scroll to 1st item , you can call  `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                    animated:YES];
```